# Invalid constructor name and Undefined class

Tags: mobile, dart, flutter

am trying to make an instance of ClassOne in ClassTwo in the code below, however I get errors `Invalid constructor name` and  `Undefined class 'instOne .person` how do I do this the right way

```
class ClassOne extends StatefulWidget {    
      @override
      ClassOneState createState() =>  ClassOneClassState();
    }

    class ClassOneState extends State<ClassOneClass> {
    var person= 'myname';
    hey(){
    print('hey hello');
    }
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[

            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }}

    // the file is in main.dart
    import 'package:cloud_fs_demo/main.dart' ;
    class ClassTwo extends StatefulWidget {    
      @override
      ClassTwoState createState() =>  ClassTwoClassState();
    }

    class ClassTwoState extends State<ClassTwoClass> {
         ClassOne instOne = ClassOne();
    //Undefined class 'instOne .person'
      instOne .person;
    //error:Invalid constructor name
    instOne .hey() ;
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create instance of `ClassOne` in `ClassTwo` because you are defining a field but think about this : when this code will execute ? `instOne.person;` . now to solve the problem you have to execute this code in the constructor function or in the initstate of the widget and the difference between them that the constructor method is executed first

**in the constructor function**

```
  var instone= ClassOne();
  _ClassTwoState(){
    instone.person="test";
  }
```

**in the initstate of the widget**

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    instone.person="test";
    super.initState();
  }
```

also you have to declare the fields and the functions you are going to use in `ClassTwo` not in `ClassTwoState`

```
class ClassOne extends StatefulWidget {
  var person= 'myname';
  hey(){
    print('hey hello');
  }
  @override
  ClassOneState createState() =>  ClassOneState();
}
```

[full example](https://gist.github.com/rahichesoft/0c9143809d7ec0a079e45b9ee5e7fedf)